# Сервер пользователь сортировка матрицы

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]У меня есть два файла, это сервер и пользователь. Вопрос такой. Программа работает с матрицей 1000 на 1000 и сортирует ее слиянием, деревом, хэш таблицей. Если я запущу на своем компьютере программу сервера и клиента мой пакет TCP будет 35000 байт в Wireshark, а если на разных то 35000 байт нету, а все 45, почему? С буфером или со стеком что то, или еще что, скажите пожалуйста.
Сервер[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import socket
import random

class SortingServer:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        # Инициализация сервера сокетов по указанному хосту и порту
        self.host = host # Присваивание хоста, к которому происходит привязка
        self.port = port # Присваивание порта, который используется для подключения
        # Создание серверного сокета с помощью модуля socket 
        # socket.AF_INET указывает, что мы используем протокол IPv4 
        # socket.SOCK_STREAM указывает, что мы работаем с TCP-сокетом
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
        self.server.bind((self.host, self.port)) # Привязка серверного сокета к заданному хосту и порту
        # Начало прослушивания подключений к серверному сокету
        # Ожидается только одно соединение
        self.server.listen(1)
        self.client, self.address = self.server.accept() # Принятие подключения от клиента
        print(f"Подключено к {self.address}")
    
    # Генерируем матрицу
    def generate_and_save_matrix(self, rows, cols, file_path):
        matrix = [[random.randint(0, 9) for _ in range(cols)] for _ in range(rows)]
        with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
            for row in matrix:
                row_str = ' '.join(f"{num: <2}" for num in row)  # Форматированный вывод с фиксированной шириной
                file.write(row_str + '\n')
        return matrix
    
    # Отправляем матрицу
    def send_matrix(self, matrix):
        matrix_str = '\n'.join([' '.join(map(str, row)) for row in matrix])
        self.client.send(matrix_str.encode())
    
    def merge_sort(self, matrix):
        # Реализация сортировки слиянием для матрицы
        sorted_matrix = []
        for row in matrix:
            sorted_row = sorted(row)
            sorted_matrix.append(sorted_row)
        return sorted_matrix
    
    # def merge_sort(self, matrix):
    #     def merge(left, right):
    #         # Реализация сортировки слиянием для матрицы
    #         result = []
    #         i = j = 0
    #         while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
    #             if left[i] < right[j]:
    #                 result.append(left[i])
    #                 i += 1
    #             else:
    #                 result.append(right[j])
    #                 j += 1
    #         result.extend(left[i:])
    #         result.extend(right[j:])
    #         return result
        
    #     def merge_sort_recursive(arr):
    #         if len(arr) <= 1:
    #             return arr
    #         mid = len(arr) // 2
    #         left = merge_sort_recursive(arr[:mid])
    #         right = merge_sort_recursive(arr[mid:])
    #         return merge(left, right)
    #     sorted_matrix = [merge_sort_recursive(row) for row in matrix]
    #     return sorted_matrix
    
    def heap_sort(self, matrix):
        # Реализация пирамидальной сортировки для матрицы
        def heapify(arr, n, i):
            largest = i
            left = 2 * i + 1
            right = 2 * i + 2

            if left < n and arr[i] < arr[left]:
                largest = left
            if right < n and arr[largest] < arr[right]:
                largest = right

            if largest != i:
                arr[i], arr[largest] = arr[largest], arr[i]
                heapify(arr, n, largest)

        def build_heap(arr):
            n = len(arr)
            for i in range(n // 2 - 1, -1, -1):
                heapify(arr, n, i)
        sorted_matrix = []
        # Применение пирамидальной сортировки к каждой строке матрицы
        for row in matrix:
            build_heap(row)
            sorted_row = []
            for i in range(len(row) - 1, -1, -1):
                row[0], row[i] = row[i], row[0]
                heapify(row, i, 0)
                sorted_row.insert(0, row.pop(0))
            sorted_matrix.append(sorted_row)
        return sorted_matrix

    def tree_sort(self, matrix):
        # Реализация сортировки деревом для матрицы
        def insert(root, key):
            if root is None:
                return {'key': key, 'left': None, 'right': None}
            if key < root['key']:
                root['left'] = insert(root['left'], key)
            else:
                root['right'] = insert(root['right'], key)
            return root

        def in_order_traversal(root, sorted_arr):
             # Рекурсивная функция обхода дерева в порядке "влево - корень - вправо"
             # # Проверяем, существует ли текущий узел (если не пуст)
            if root:
                in_order_traversal(root['left'], sorted_arr) #  # Рекурсивно обходим левое поддерево
                sorted_arr.append(root['key']) # # Добавляем значение текущего узла в список
                in_order_traversal(root['right'], sorted_arr) #  # Рекурсивно обходим правое поддерево

        sorted_matrix = [] # Создание списка для хранения отсортированных строк
        # Итерация по каждой строке в матрице
        for row in matrix: 
            root = None # Инициализация переменной для хранения дерева текущей строки
            # Добавление каждого элемента строки в дерево
            for num in row:
                root = insert(root, num)
            sorted_row = [] # Создание списка для отсортированных значений текущей строки
            in_order_traversal(root, sorted_row) # Обход дерева в порядке "влево - корень - вправо" и добавление значений в список
            sorted_matrix.append(sorted_row) # Добавление отсортированной строки в список отсортированных строк матрицы
        return sorted_matrix

    def binary_search(self, matrix, target):
        # Реализация бинарного поиска в матрице
        def binary_search_row(arr, target):
            low = 0
            high = len(arr) - 1
            while low <= high:
                mid = (low + high) // 2
                if arr[mid] == target:
                    return True
                elif arr[mid] < target:
                    low = mid + 1
                else:
                    high = mid - 1
            return False

        for row in matrix:
            if binary_search_row(row, target):
                return True
        return False

    def hash_table_search(self, matrix, target):
        # Реализация поиска с использованием хэш-таблицы
        hash_table = {}
        for row_index, row in enumerate(matrix):
            for col_index, val in enumerate(row):
                if val not in hash_table:
                    hash_table[val] = []
                hash_table[val].append((row_index, col_index))

        if target in hash_table:
            return True, hash_table[target]
        return False, []
    
    # Обработка запросов клиента
    def handle_client(self):
        while True:
            choice = self.client.recv(1024).decode()
            if not choice:
                break
            # Обработка выбора пользователя
            if choice == '1':
                matrix = self.generate_and_save_matrix(1000, 1000, 'matrix.txt')  # Создание и сохранение матрицы
                self.send_matrix(matrix)
            elif choice == '2':
            # Получение выбора сортировки от клиента и применение соответствующего метода сортировки
                sort_choice = self.client.recv(1024).decode()
                if sort_choice == '1':
                    sorted_matrix = self.merge_sort(matrix)
                elif sort_choice == '2':
                    sorted_matrix = self.heap_sort(matrix)
                elif sort_choice == '3':
                # Получение выбора поиска от клиента и выполнение соответствующего поиска
                    sorted_matrix = self.tree_sort(matrix)
                self.send_matrix(sorted_matrix)
            elif choice == '3':
                search_choice = self.client.recv(1024).decode()
                target = int(self.client.recv(1024).decode())
                if search_choice == '1':
                    found = self.binary_search(matrix, target)
                    self.client.send(str(found).encode())
                elif search_choice == '2':
                    found, positions = self.hash_table_search(matrix, target)
                    self.client.send(str(found).encode())
                    if found:
                        positions_str = ', '.join([f"({pos[0]}, {pos[1]})" for pos in positions])
                        self.client.send(positions_str.encode())
    # Закрытие сервера                    
    def close(self):
        self.server.close()
# ip.addr== 192.168.0.123 and tcp
if __name__ == "__main__":
    host = '192.168.0.123' # Указание IP-адреса хоста
    port = 12345 # Указание порта для подключения
    server = SortingServer(host, port) # Создание сервера с указанными параметрами
    server.handle_client() # Обработка запросов клиента
    server.close() # Закрытие сервера
    
# 1) Фрагментация данных: Если передаваемые данные слишком большие, они могут быть разделены на фрагменты для передачи по сети. Это может привести к разным размерам пакетов.
# 2) Буферизация: Размеры пакетов могут зависеть от того, как данные обрабатываются в буферах. Например, если данные отправляются блоками, размеры могут различаться.
# 3) Протокол TCP: TCP может управлять потоком данных и разбивать их на сегменты, чтобы обеспечить эффективную передачу. Это может вызвать изменение размера пакетов.
# 4) Работа сокетов: Настройки сокетов, такие как размер буфера, также могут влиять на размер передаваемых пакетов.
```

Клиент

```
import socket

class SortingClient:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
         # Инициализация клиента сокетов с указанным хостом и портом
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.client.connect((self.host, self.port))
    
    # Отображение меню выбора действий для пользователя
    def display_menu(self):
        print("1. Сгенерировать матрицу")
        print("2. Отсортировать матрицу")
        print("3. Поиск в матрице")
        choice = input("Введите ваш выбор: ")
        return choice
    
    # Отображение методов сортировки для выбора пользователя
    def display_sorting_methods(self):
        print("Выберите метод сортировки:")
        print("1. Сортировка слиянием")
        print("2. Пирамидальная сортировка")
        print("3. Сортировка деревом")
        method = input("Введите выбранный метод сортировки: ")
        return method
    
    # Отображение методов поиска для выбора пользователя
    def display_search_methods(self):
        print("Выберите метод поиска:")
        print("1. Бинарный поиск")
        print("2. Поиск с использованием хэш-таблицы")
        method = input("Введите выбранный метод поиска: ")
        return method
    
    # Получение данных матрицы от сервера
    def receive_matrix(self):
        matrix_data = self.client.recv(4096).decode()
        rows = matrix_data.split('\n')
        sorted_matrix = []
        with open('savematrix.txt', 'w') as file:
            for row in rows:
                formatted_row = row.split()
                row_str = ' '.join(f"{num: <2}" for num in formatted_row)
                sorted_matrix.append(row_str)
                file.write(row_str + '\n')
        for row_str in sorted_matrix:
            print(row_str)
    
    # Отправка выбора действия на сервер
    def send_choice(self, choice):
        # через сокет
        self.client.send(choice.encode())
    
    # Отправка выбранного метода сортировки на сервер
    def send_sorting_method(self, method):
        # через сокет
        self.client.send(method.encode())
    
    # Отправка целевого значения для поиска на сервер
    def send_target(self, target):
        # через сокет
        self.client.send(target.encode())
    
    # Получение результата от сервера
    def receive_result(self):
        # через сокет и его отображение
        result = self.client.recv(4096).decode()
        print(result)
    
    # Закрытие соединения клиента
    def close(self):
        self.client.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    host = '192.168.0.123' # IP-адрес сервера
    port = 12345 # Порт сервера
    client = SortingClient(host, port) # Создание клиента с указанными параметрами
    while True:
        choice = client.display_menu() # Отображение меню и получение выбора пользователя
        client.send_choice(choice) # Отправка выбранного действия на сервер
        if choice == '1':
            client.receive_matrix() # Получение сгенерированной матрицы от сервера
        elif choice == '2':
            sorting_method = client.display_sorting_methods() # Отображение методов сортировки
            client.send_sorting_method(sorting_method) # Отправка выбранного метода сортировки на сервер
            client.receive_matrix()  # Получение отсортированной матрицы
        elif choice == '3':
            search_method = client.display_search_methods() # Отображение методов поиска
            client.send_choice(search_method) # Отправка выбранного метода поиска на сервер
            target = input("Введите целевое значение для поиска: ")
            client.send_target(target) # Отправка целевого значения для поиска на сервер
            client.receive_result()  # Получение результата поиска
    client.close() # Закрытие соединения с сервером
```

Comment: «Пакет TCP» не может быть один из-за MTU 1500 байт. Где и как конкретно вы увидели эти «все 45»?

Comment: @andreymal lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536

Comment: @eri вот именно что lo, а не «на разных»

Comment: Представьте код, не совсем понятен вопрос.

Comment: Добавил код к вопросу, как просили. Есть у сервера комментарии, что в теории может быть.

Comment: Может
 Если сервер и клиент запущены на разных компьютерах, то данные должны пересылаться через сеть. Это может привести к фрагментации пакетов, особенно если размер передаваемых данных превышает размер MTU. Фрагментация может привести к увеличению числа пакетов и, следовательно, к увеличению общего объема трафика.

Comment: Ну или. Когда большой и на одном компьютере. Когда программы запускаются на одном компьютере (localhost), данные обмениваются через loopback интерфейс, который является виртуальным сетевым интерфейсом 
и не создает физического сетевого трафика. В этом случае операционная система может использовать более эффективные методы передачи данных между процессами, 
включая более крупные пакеты данных, чтобы уменьшить накладные расходы на передачу данных через виртуальный интерфейс.

Comment: И на нескольких.  Когда программы запускаются на разных компьютерах в одной локальной сети или через Интернет, данные передаются через физическую сеть, и операционная система 
должна учитывать ограничения сетевых протоколов и размеры MTU для эффективной передачи данных. Обычно MTU для Ethernet составляет 1500 байт, 
и большие объемы данных могут разбиваться на меньшие фрагменты для передачи.
Может так. Там еще вопрос был что то с дампом, что там происходит?